# How to disable blinding QR codes?

Tags: iphone, ios

In some apps when I open a QR code, my phone's screen's brightness will be turned to 100%.

How can I stop that from happening in all cases?

Comment: Feedback to the app producer? It's usually set like that so a barcode reader can see the QR code in most, but especially bright lighting conditions

Comment: @AndyGriffiths it's a built-in feature, e.g. apple's wallet app does it

Comment: Feedback to Apple then ;-)